# Test Automation framework for end to end integration testing

Tags: testing, automation

The application that I test consists of multiple integration components distributed across different platforms. The system integration test scenarios cover creation of transactions from GUI, validating data in DB, checking remote paths for file creation, file transfer to other paths etc. Can someone suggest a good automation framework( Open source if available) to write automation script for such integration scenarios? I have worked with Selenium primarily for GUI automation but the current scenario involves automation beyond GUI( DB queries, services, checking XML file creation in remote paths etc).Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is technology stack?

Answer (score 0):

I think for other stuffs you have mentioned to automate is done through any service side scripting language like Java, PHP, etc.
For DB queries you can go with java abstraction library or by using simple JDBC connection and functions.
For Services testing: You can use services testing framework like for Java use Jersey, etc.
For checking XML file creation: It can be validated through simple java streams handling functions.
And for Remote paths validation: It can be handled through Java FTP library.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements for automating integration scenarios that go beyond GUI testing, a suitable open-source automation framework to consider is "Robot Framework". Robot Framework is a flexible and extensible framework that supports a wide range of testing scenarios, including GUI, API, database, and file operations. It provides a keyword-driven approach that simplifies test script creation and maintenance.

**GUI Automation**: use Selenium Library

**API Testing**: Robot Framework has built-in libraries

**Database Testing**: Robot Framework has built-in libraries

**File Operations**: Robot Framework has built-in libraries

**Note**: Robot Framework requires "Python" to run